# Loading Twitter profile pictures with Twitter V2

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter-api-v2, profile-picture, twitter-api-v1

I used to access Twitter profile pictures with API V1.1 using "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json" URL. But with new Twitter developer subscription plans, this flow is not available for free package. I want to access these profile pictures without authenticating individual users with Twitter login.

Is it possible to do this with free subscription plan using Twitter API V2?

I tried using `"https://api.twitter.com/2/users/by/username/"+username` URL, but it requires individual user authentication. I want to access profile images from app level as done in V1.1.